# When I kik a ball at velocity Vo, angle alpha, from the ground..(no air resistance)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I have the force acting on the ball equals to F = (Fx,Fy) = (0, -mg)?
I mean I understand that I have the mg force on the y axis, pointing down, and I understand that there is no additional force on the x-axis, but shouldn't I have also a force (both in the x axis and yaxis) that comes from the fact that I kicked the ball?

I mean shouldn't it be something like F = (Fx, Fy) = (ma(x)+0, -mg + ma(y))?
Thanks

Comment: What force are you exerting on the ball after it has left your foot?  That is, unless your name is Yoda.

Comment: Without air resistance the ball is always going to follow _the same path_ when started from the same initial conditions, regardless of the method of launching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual assumption is that the kick changes the initial condition of the ball. Your foot made contact at $t=0$, and exerted a large force $F$ during a short time interval $\Delta t$. If we assume the force exerted was constant, then at the time the ball leaves the foot, it has momentum $p = mv = F\Delta t$, and it has moved a very short distance $d = \frac12 a t^2 = \frac{F \Delta t^2}{2 m} = \frac{v\Delta t}{2}$; and the shorter $\Delta t$, the less far the ball moved during the kick (for the same velocity).

If you ignore that small amount of motion, then you can say the problem starts when the foot stops making contact with the ball; and you start the calculation with the ball at a certain velocity $v$, only subject to the force of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

The kick itself just gives the ball some initial velocity and then the movement is considered after the ball already reached this velocity. To put it a bit more formally, we are not interested in the dynamics, only in the kinematics of the "kicking" part.